# How to establish websocket connection on tomcat9 server

Tags: tomcat, websocket, tomcat9

I have set up a tomcat9 server via the service Kamatera. I have ssh:ed to the server and deployed a simple websocket application. However, I get a handshake error. Also, when I try https://{server-url}.io/examples I can do the Servlets examples and JSP examples, but when trying the websocket examples I get an error code (See image).

[image]

I thought websockets for Tomcat should work out of the box, but does anyone know if there are some configurations needed to be made? Or if this Kamatera service is rerouting/blocking some traffic?

Answer (score 0):

The Tomcat WebSocket examples do work out of the box.

Might you be connecting via a reverse proxy? They typically do not support WebSocket without special configuration.

Comment: I will try to check this

Comment: After googling it seems I should look for this header to verify if reverse proxy is there X-Forwarded-For. So I found this header in the http request for the handshake, it was X-Forwarded-For {some ip}. So I probably have a reverse proxy?